# Highcharts Export To CSV With Delimited Columns

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, plugins, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts [EXPORT-CSV](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) plugin to export my chart series data to an Excel File. I have the following code which generates the .CSV file:

```
            {
                textKey: 'downloadCSV',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.downloadCSV();
                }
            }
```

As a result, when I click the button an excel file is generated but the data is in the following format, everything is in one single column:

DateTime;"CIFQ:  DRAYAGE"
04-30-2015;296
05-01-2015;270
05-29-2015;350
06-30-2015;350
07-30-2015;1833
12-14-2015;300
12-18-2015;350

Instead I'd like the data to be separated into two columns using the ';' delimiter. You can see that this is possible from the following jsfiddle if you click the dropdown and select 'Download CSV':
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/j4w4s0mw/

How do I get it so that excel separates my data into two separate columns as soon as the file opens?

Comment: If you use the default `itemDelimiter`, it works fine. Why change it to a semi-colon, if the comma works?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out!

The website saying the following:

> exporting.csv.itemDelimiter The item delimiter, defaults to ,. Use ;
>   for direct import to Excel.

But it turns out Excel uses ',' as a column delimiter.

Comment: Excel will "use" whatever delimiter you tell it to. But it recognizes comma delimited files without requiring user input to do so.